# How to apply math.ceil function to the part of objective function in python pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Am trying to apply the `math.ceil` function on one part of the objective function in python-pulp. But, Am getting

```
"TypeError: must be real number, not LpAffineExpression" error.
```

Following is the example.

```
models = [A, B, C, D, E]
modelCost = {A: 10, B: 15, C: 20, D: 25, E: 30}
TotalModelsCost = pulp.lpSum([(model*modelCost[model]) for model in models])
OverHeadCost = (math.ceil(pulp.lpSum([model for model in models])/4))*100

prob += TotalModelsCost + OverHeadCost
```

How to apply the `ceil` function to `OverHeadCost`?

Comment: You can't use `ceil` in a linear program -- it's a nonlinear function. There are ways to make it happen, but is it essential that you round that part of the objective function up? Your job (and the solver's job) will be easier if you allow it to be fractional.

Comment: Thank you Divyanshu for your reply. 
Yes, applying `ceil` is essential. Can you please tell the way, how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new decision variable called, say, `OverHeadCostCeil`, which is a *general integer* (not binary) variable:

```
OverHeadCostCeil = pulp.LpVariable('OverHeadCostCeil', 0, None, LpInteger)
```

Require `OverHeadCostCeil >= OverHeadCost` via a constraint:

```
prob += OverHeadCostCeil >= OverHeadCost
```

Replace term in objective function:

```
prob += TotalModelsCost + OverHeadCostCeil
```

Then solve. Note that you need to use a solver that can handle general integer variables.

Comment: Sure thing. Don't forget you can vote/accept an answer to say "thanks" too. :)